# Integral point inside a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices

Given four points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, is there an efficient method to determine if the convex hull contains an integral point $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$? If it helps, I can assume the convex hull is a quadrilateral.

Comment: Not sure if this is much help, but it could be possible to split the quadrilateral into two triangles and use Pick's theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem (but this only works if the vertices of the quadrilateral are integer points.)

Comment: @OldJohn Yes thanks, but in my application the vertices will be general rational points. Raymond's reference below to Yanagisawa's paper might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps that this paper of Yanagisawa will help ['A Simple Algorithm for Lattice Point Counting in Rational Polygons'](http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/people/yanagis/papers/RT0622.pdf).

It begins with an historical overview with the important contributions of Pick and Barvinok (based on Ehrhart polynomials as you may find in his ['Lattice Points, Polyhedra, and Complexity'](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/lectures.pdf)) before proposing their own variant.

Hoping it helped a little,